# knockoutjs ko.toJs (ko.toJSON) doesn't work

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using knockoutjs version 2.2.0 and have the following situation:

**Javasript Code**
Here is my javascript code with 3 models: 'Tab1', 'Tab2' and 'viewModel'

```
var CustomExport = {
    Tab1: function () {
        this.tab1Array = ko.observableArray([
            {name: "Tab1 Item1"},
            {name: "Tab1 Item2"},
            {name: "Tab1 Item3"}
        ]);
    },
    Tab2: function () {
        this.tab2Array = ko.observableArray([
            {name: "Tab2 Item1"},
            {name: "Tab2 Item2"},
            {name: "Tab2 Item3"}
        ]);
    },
    viewModel: function () {
        this.myTab1 = new CustomExport.Tab1();
        this.myTab2 = new CustomExport.Tab2();
        this.grabData = function(){
            alert(ko.toJS(CustomExport.viewModel));
        };
    }    
}

ko.applyBindings(new CustomExport.viewModel());
```

So, in general I have 2 models and I want to grab all data from those models into one "viewModel" model as a json object, the *grabData* function should alert me the models data.


Here is my **HTML Code**

```
<div data-bind="with: myTab1">
    <ul data-bind="template: {name: 'tabTmpl', foreach: tab1Array}"></ul>
</div>
<br/>
<div>------------------------------------------</div>
<br/>
<div data-bind="with: myTab2">
    <ul data-bind="template: {name: 'tabTmpl', foreach: tab2Array}"></ul>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: grabData" value="Grab all data from Models" />


<script id="tabTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
    </li>
</script>
```

The issue is the following:
Clicking on the '`Grab all data from the models`' button I should get an alert which must contains data from 2 models ('Tab1', 'Tab2') as a **json object**, but currently I got the following alert message:

```
function () {
    this.myTab1 = new CustomExport.Tab1();
    this.myTab2 = new CustomExport.Tab2();
    this.grabData = function(){
        alert(ko.toJS(CustomExport.viewModel));
    };
}
```

Also, I have created it in my jsFiddle [Click here to see an example](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/4qKhE/)

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: CustomExport.viewModel is not the actual reference to viewModel, replace it with this because this is the actual viewmodel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `this` instead of `CustomExport.viewModel`:

```
this.grabData = function(){
    console.log(ko.toJS(this));
};
```

But it is better to create closure for `this`:

```
function () {
    var self = this;
    self.myTab1 = new CustomExport.Tab1();
    self.myTab2 = new CustomExport.Tab2();
    self.grabData = function(){
        alert(ko.toJS(self));
    };
}
```

Comment: And even better is to move grabData to prototype declaration

Comment: Thanks guys (Anders and Artem), you are really helped me!